# how to merge only specific non - continuous changes from one branch to other

Tags: svn, merge

How can I merge/apply patch from one branch to other branch.Both branch has nearly same  merge history from other branch .Ex :
Branch 1 and branch 2 both has nearly same code merge from BranchX ,Branch Y ,Branch Z (parent branches ) .But within interval of merging , large delta code change was also committed in Branch1 .And this delta was committed on code base of Branch X , branch Y and branch Z . (As I said within itnervals of merging delta was also committed)
Now I want to merge/apply only that delta change from Branch1 to branch2.

In this scenario , I think Auto-merge is not a good option as it will duplicate changes 
as both branches as same parent branches but with different merge history.
Please advise any good approach to apply only that delta changes (nearly 2000 files ) from branch1 to branch 2.
Will applying Patch will be good option  ? AS I think Auto-merging might result in duplicacy and unwanted conflicts.
Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a recent version of SVN (1.7 or higher I think) then merge tracking is supposedly smart enough to avoid merging revisions that have been properly recorded as merged.

Since you apparently have thousands of commits you want, not just one or two, the easiest method is to just try an automatic merge. If the merge causes problems, then you've not lost anything; you can always revert.

In the worst case, I would bet that any conflicts are easily solvable using a good 3-way diff tool like KDiff3 or Meld, since most of the conflicting changes will already have been applied in the destination branch.

Note that if a complete automated merge gives difficulties, you can try breaking the merge up into smaller more manageable chunks. First merge the first 100-200 contiguous revisions, then the next 100-200, and so on, until you have merged all revisions. With more bite-sized pieces the automated merge algorithms sometimes have an easier time, and any manual conflict resolution will DEFINITELY be easier.

Comment: Aplogies for Late reply,Ben Your inputs if I use --ignore ancestry and --ignore whitespace in auto-merge command .Is there any harm using these options ?

Comment: Why would you use --ignore-ancestry? If I understand correctly, the point of that option is for when the two branches don't actually share any history. If they actually do share history it will probably just make things more complicated. --ignore-whitespace probably won't affect much in terms of merge difficulty, unless it makes the merge easier. Either way, breaking the merge up into smaller chunks should make it easier.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like, out of many commits on Branch 1, you only want to merge over the changes from one or two commits. For this, use a "cherry pick" merge by specifying exactly what revision(s) you want to merge. For example,

```
svn merge -c 1234,4567 http://example.com/svn/branches/branch1
```

See http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.html#svn.ref.svn.sw.change and http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.merge.html for the details.

Comment: yup I know about this ... but there are around non contiguous 1000 rev#.And its not possible to use cherry picking .Any other workaround here will be much appreciated !

Comment: Will it will be good if I merge again from Branch 1 to branch2 .It contains around 60 % code same on both side .Will this duplicacy create any problem.

Comment: TortoiseSVN, at least in version 1.8, has a feature where revisions which have already been merged can be hidden. I'm still not 100% clear on when this feature is available, but perhaps it will help you quickly choose all the revisions you want when selecting revisions for a cherry-pick. But I misunderstood your question, and would probably try an automatic merge first.